# How to do dynamically generated LineChart in as3.0 like this

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, linechart

I have been trying to figure out a way to create a LineChart that contains numerous LineSeries based off data in an ArrayCollection.
To be more specific, let's say that we have an ArrayCollection about the remote object which will be user for get data , as such:
a KC CLASS which attribute include wordLocal,wordsCount,words

```
        var arr:ArrayCollection = event.result as ArrayCollection;
            var kc:KC= new KC();
            for(var i:int=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                kc=arr.getItemAt(i) as KC;
                var word:String = String(kc.words);
                var row:int = kc.wordLocal as int;
                var wc:int= kc.wordsCount as int;
                datasource.addItem({rows:row,word:wc});
}
```

I want to create a LineChart that contains : the words rows localtion and wc times appeat in total ,such as word "a", The line for "a"  on the single line,which xField is rows,yField is wc .

I was thinking that I would probably have to create the LineSeries dynamically

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks